# Get woocommerce get order total value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How could I get order total value of finished woocommerce order into my converse code?

The following code is bellow. I have tried everything and still getting fatal error. The code is located in functions.php in my theme.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page' );

function bbloomer_conversion_tracking_thank_you_page() {
?>


<!-- Mìøicí kód Sklik.cz -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var seznam_cId = 100060787;
var seznam_value = null;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.seznam.cz/rs/static/rc.js" async></script>
<?php
}
```

I need to modify - > var seznam_value = null; to get the value - price (how much money does the order costs) of finished order to manage conversions on my website.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)

Comment: It would be great if you could tell me what code to input insted of null vallue because I have tried almost everything and still got an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the thing

```
<!-- Mìøicí kód Sklik.cz -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var seznam_cId = 100060787;
var seznam_value =<?php echo ($order->get_subtotal()); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Trough `woocommerce_thankyou()` you have access to the `$order_id` parameter
>
> `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`

```php
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    // Get $order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var order_total = <?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>;
    console.log( order_total );
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Great code, it could help but It did not help in this case, I have post the answer to the topic. Thank you for your help anyway. :)